# Glide 4.9.0 can't use MyAppGlideModule to load firebase picture

Tags: android, android-glide, firebaseui

I use Glide 4.9.0 to load pictures, but I want to load firebase pictures, so I create a class `MyAppGlideModule` to override, after that I clean my project and rebuild it, but it still can't use `GlideApp` to load pictures, `MyAppGlideModule` still show not used.

I didn't add `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'` in my code, because after I `migrate to AndroidX`, it will get compile error.

How can I fixed it, or it has any way to show firebase pictures, thank you.

Here is my `MyAppGlideModule` class:

```
@GlideModule
public class MyAppGlideModule extends AppGlideModule {

    @Override
    public void registerComponents(Context context, Glide glide, Registry registry) {
        registry.append(StorageReference.class, InputStream.class,
                new FirebaseImageLoader.Factory());
    }

}
```

Here is I want to load pictures in recyclerview:

```
StorageReference pathReference = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child(post.img);

                Glide.with(mContext)
                        .load(pathReference)
                        .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE)
                        .placeholder(R.drawable.ic_load_img)
                        .into(((PostViewHolder) holder).postcard_img);
```

Here is my bulide.gradle:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:2.0.2'
    implementation 'com.nostra13.universalimageloader:universal-image-loader:1.9.5'
    implementation 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:annotations:4.9.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:17.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:18.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:18.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:18.1.1'
    implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:5.0.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:audience-network-sdk:5.4.1'
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:5.4.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.0.0'
    implementation files('libs/jsch-0.1.55.jar')
}
```

if I add `annotationProcessor 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.9.0'` in build.grade, I will get these error code:

```
C:/Users/Myapp/AndroidStudioProjects/PGapp  
app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/gmpsykr/goma/GlideOptions.java 
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist    
error: package android.support.annotation does not exist    
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
error: cannot find symbol class CheckResult 
app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/gmpsykr/goma/GlideRequest.java 
app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/gmpsykr/goma/GlideRequests.java    
app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedRequestManagerFactory.java 
app/build/generated/source/apt/debug/com/bumptech/glide/GeneratedAppGlideModuleImpl.java
```

Comment: can you replace this?
com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:5.0.0
To
com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-storage:4.1.0

Than clean project and restart Android Studio.

Comment: @PrashantArvind I tried your method, but I still can't use GlideApp and my pictures still not show.

Comment: can you send your code zip? if its just testing project!

Comment: Please provide your error log

Comment: @PrashantArvind sorry, it's not a testing project, I can't send my project to you.

Comment: @SilverskyTechnology I update my post and add the error log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, add

```
implementation "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
annotationProcessor "com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0"
```

it seems Glide 4.9.0 not support AndroidX yet.